# Crawl angularjs based website in python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

Trying to crawl a [website](https://www.kva.se/en/utlysningar/stipendier-bidrag) which is angular based. I am getting TimeOutException on looking up for any element

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/[contains(@class, 'news--boxes')]")))
```

Tried several html classes and tags but still no luck. Is there a specific way to crawl angular based website which is not this?

Full Code : http://collabedit.com/javk4

Comment: `(By.XPATH, "//div/[contains(@class, 'news--boxes')]")` identifies the whole container. Which attribute of which element are you trying crawl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be a simple typo in XPath

Just remove extra slash after `div` as below:

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'news--boxes')]"
```

Comment: yeah. there is a typo in xpath rule. removing "/" after div worked for me either.

Comment: `"//[contains(@class, 'news--boxes')"` is also wrong! Use exact XPath as in my answer: `"//div[contains(@class, 'news--boxes')]"`